# How to wrap a C function with variable arguments using SWIG

Tags: c, lua, arguments, swig

I'm trying to wrap a C function with variable arguments using SWIG which looks like the following.

```
void post(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char buf[MAXPDSTRING];
    va_list ap;
    t_int arg[8];
    int i;
    va_start(ap, fmt);
    vsnprintf(buf, MAXPDSTRING-1, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    strcat(buf, "\n");

    dopost(buf);
}
```

But When I run the function in Lua, it only works when I use 1 argument.
I couldn't write in the following style.

```
pd.post("NUM : %d", 123);
```

And I get the following error.

```
Error in post expected 1..1 args, got 2
```

Is it possible to wrap a C function with variable arguments using SWIG?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks, I read the link but I still don't understand how to wrap the function and whether it is possible in Lua using SWIG. And the link only has Python examples. I would appreciate more detailed answer.

Comment: As you have seen from this page there is no sensible way to wrap C vararg functions unless you are willing to write an awful lot of boilerplate and your own wrapper for the function, defeating the purpose of SWIG.  Perhaps you should rethink your design.

Comment: I might be able to hack something together and/or write a patch for SWIG that does this properly. Are you able to do either of a) add a version of `post` which operates on `va_list` or b) limit the number of ABIs you need to support (e.g. just linux/x86) at all, which would slightly simplify adding varargs support to the lua backend.

Comment: @Flexo a) Yes b) No, I don't want to limit the number of ABIs to support.

Comment: One more question: is using GCC extensions acceptable?

Comment: @Flexo Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Not really an answer, because I didn't find a way to override SWIG's argument checking, so I could process varargs myself.  This can be solved by combining the methods I show below with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686022).

## Links and further reading

- [Variable Length Arguments (a.k.a, "The horror. The horror.")](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Varargs.html) in the SWIG documentation
- [Create va_list dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351056) on Stack Overflow
- [How do I fill a va_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703770) on Stack Overflow

## Plain C wrapper

I prepared an example how to convert a call to a variadic Lua function to a variadic C function using [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) ([documentation](https://www.manpagez.com/info/libffi)).

Currently the code only handles `int` (requires Lua 5.3), `double` and `const char *` arguments.  It can be trivially extended to more types as well.  Keep in mind that this approach is **extremely unsafe**.  Using an unsupported format will result in a segmentation fault (the format string goes unchecked).  For example compiling against Lua 5.2 and trying to use the integer format like so

```lua
printf("Hello World! %d %d %d\n", 1, 5, 7)
```

will result in

```
Hello World! 0 0 0
```

if you are lucky and it doesn't segfault on you, but running the program in a memory debugger like valgrind will reveal that you are doing nasty things.

```c
// clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c99 -g -I/usr/include/lua5.3 test.c -llua5.3 -lffi

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#include <ffi.h>

static int l_printf(lua_State *L) {
    typedef union {
        int integer;
        double number;
        const char *string;
    } variant;

    int argc = lua_gettop(L);
    variant *argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(variant));

    ffi_cif cif;
    ffi_type **types = malloc(argc * sizeof(ffi_type *));
    void **values = malloc(argc * sizeof(void *));

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        int j = i + 1;
        switch (lua_type(L, j)) {
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
#if LUA_VERSION_NUM >= 503
            if (lua_isinteger(L, j)) {
                types[i] = &ffi_type_sint;
                argv[i].integer = lua_tointeger(L, j);
                values[i] = &argv[i].integer;
            } else
#endif
            {
                types[i] = &ffi_type_double;
                argv[i].number = lua_tonumber(L, j);
                values[i] = &argv[i].number;
            }
            break;
        case LUA_TSTRING:
            types[i] = &ffi_type_pointer;
            argv[i].string = lua_tostring(L, j);
            values[i] = &argv[i].string;
            break;
        default:
            puts("Unhandled argment type");
            abort();
            break;
        }
    }

    // If preparing the FFI call fails we simply push -1 to indicate
    // that printf failed
    int result = -1;
    if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, argc, &ffi_type_sint, types) ==
        FFI_OK) {
        ffi_call(&cif, (void (*)())printf, &result, values);
    }

    free(values);
    free(types);
    free(argv);

    lua_pushinteger(L, result);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <script.lua>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_pushcfunction(L, l_printf);
    lua_setglobal(L, "printf");

    if (luaL_dofile(L, argv[1]) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "lua: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_close(L);
        return 1;
    }

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Compiling against Lua 5.3 we can run the following example:

```lua
print(printf("Hello World! %d %d %d\n", 1, 5, 7) .. " bytes written")
print(printf("Hello %d %f World! %s\n", 1, 3.14, "ABC") .. " bytes written")
```

Output:

```
Hello World! 1 5 7
19 bytes written
Hello 1 3.140000 World! ABC
28 bytes written
```

## An attempt in SWIG

I have come up with a variant which is usable from within SWIG, but makes the assumption that all arguments are convertible to `string`.  Here I simply declare `printf` to be a function taking ten arguments of type `string` (if you need more, just increase the number).

```
%varargs(10, const char * = NULL) printf;
int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
```

This would call the `printf` function with 10 strings, which are by default empty (`NULL`).  Therefore I wrote an `action` which converts each argument to its proper type (`int`, `double`, `string`).  Because the SWIG argument checker calls `lua_tostring` on each argument already, a call to `lua_type` would just always result in `LUA_TSTRING`, no matter what the actual argument type was.  That is why I'm using `lua_tointegerx` and `lua_tonumberx`, to convert from the string back to the original type.  Combined with an extremely inefficient fallthrough based on succeeding conversion, this gives us a wrapper similar to the plain C wrapper presented above.

```c
%module printf

%{
#include <ffi.h>
%}

%feature("action") printf {
    typedef union {
        int integer;
        double number;
        const char *string;
    } variant;

    int argc = lua_gettop(L);
    variant *argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(variant));

    ffi_cif cif;
    ffi_type **types = malloc(argc * sizeof(ffi_type *));
    void **values = malloc(argc * sizeof(void *));

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        int j = i + 1;

        int flag = 0;

        types[i] = &ffi_type_sint;
        argv[i].integer = lua_tointegerx(L, j, &flag);
        values[i] = &argv[i].integer;
        if (flag) { continue; }

        types[i] = &ffi_type_double;
        argv[i].number = lua_tonumberx(L, j, &flag);
        values[i] = &argv[i].number;
        if (flag) { continue; }

        types[i] = &ffi_type_pointer;
        argv[i].string = lua_tostring(L, j);
        values[i] = &argv[i].string;
        if (argv[i].string) { continue; }

        puts("Unhandled argment type");
        abort();
        break;
    }

    // If preparing the FFI call fails we simply push -1 to indicate
    // that printf failed
    result = -1;
    if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, argc, &ffi_type_sint, types) ==
        FFI_OK) {
        ffi_call(&cif, (void (*)())printf, &result, values);
    }

    free(values);
    free(types);
    free(argv);
};

%varargs(10, const char * = NULL) printf;
int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
```

```bash
swig -lua test.i
clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c99 -I/usr/include/lua5.3 -fPIC -shared test_wrap.c -o printf.so -llua5.3 -lffi
```

```lua
local printf = require"printf"
printf.printf("Hello %d %f %s World!\n", 1, 3.14, "ABC")
```

```
Hello 1 3.140000 ABC World!
```

## Closing remarks

As a final note, this is a horribly inefficient way of formatting strings in Lua.  I am not aware of any variadic function in C other than the `printf` family of functions, i.e. all of them perform string formatting.  This is done much more efficiently in Lua using `string.format` and a function call like

```lua
do_something("Hello %d %f %s World!\n", 1, 3.14, "ABC")
```

should simply be avoided in favour of the slightly more verbose, but much more robust

```lua
do_something(string.format("Hello %d %f %s World!\n", 1, 3.14, "ABC"))
```

Comment: This is similar to the idea I had in mind. I think I've got a way to get at the raw varargs though, but not done the FFI bits.

Comment: @Flexo How would you have dealt with SWIG's argument checking?  I wanted to use `typemap (...)` as in the Python example in the official docs but SWIG determined `...` to be only a single parameter.

Comment: @HenriMenke Hey, I didn't even know there was such a thing like `string.format()` in Lua as I'm a beginner. I think that would be enough for what I wanted to do. I just wanted to build something similar to `print()` in Lua since I can't print anything to a console using `print()` in my host program. I need to send string to the program in order to do so. That's why I was trying to wrap `post()` which does it. I just wanted to be able to print multiple variables more easily like how `print()` works.

Comment: @HenriMenke I had enough fun writing it that even though I didn't follow through with the rest of the solution here it made enough of a question to post as a self-answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50686022/168175