# Can I modify a va_list before passing it on?

Tags: objective-c, variadic-functions

In my attempts to understand what I can and can't do with a va_list in (Objective-)C, I came across this little puzzle. I was hoping to create a category on `NSString` that would simplify the `stringWithFormat:` message a bit in some cases, just for the fun of it. What I was aiming for was being able to use the implementation like this:

```
[@"My %@ format %@!" formattedWith:@"super", @"rocks"];
```

Hoping to end up with a string saying "`My super format rocks!`". My (incorrect) method implementation looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)formattedWith:(NSString *)arguments, ...
{
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, arguments);
    NSString *formatted = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:self arguments:list] autorelease];
    va_end(list);
    return formatted;
}
```

Now the problem is that as soon as `va_start()` is called, the va_list is 'shortened' (for lack of a better word) and only contains the rest of the arguments (in the case of the example only `@"rocks"` remains, plus the calling object which I don't care about). What's passed onto the `initWithFormat:` message therefore renders the wrong kind of result.

On to the question. Are there ways to *modify* the va_list before I pass it to the `initWithFormat:` message, so I can somehow shift the first argument back onto the list?

I'm not looking for an iterative process where I loop through the va_list myself, I'm looking to understand the limits of va_list as a whole. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this blog post is helpful http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `va_list` can not be [modified safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988290/populating-a-va-list). The `va_start` argument also requires an argument to start the list which is excluded. The ways to work around this are to either pass an additional useless argument or use variadic macros.

```
//Method declaration
-(NSString*)formattedWith:(NSString*)ignored,...;

//Opt 1 (pass anything for first value)
[@"My %@ format %@!" formattedWith:nil, @"super", @"rocks"];

//Opt 2 (create a macro for the arguments)
#define VA_OPT(...) nil, ##__VA_ARGS__ //VARIADIC OPTIONAL
[@"My %@ format %@!" formattedWith:VA_OPT(@"super", @"rocks"];

//Opt 3 (just create a macro for the whole string format)
//Obviously you should just use the NSString method directly before resorting to this
#define FORMATTED_NSSTRING(str, ...) [NSString stringWithFormat:str, ##__VA_ARGS__]
FORMATTED_NSSTRING(@"My %@ format %@!", @"super", @"rocks")
```