# How to access N number of parameters in C Function & passing the same N into next?

Tags: objective-c, c, function, parameters, arguments

Say for example this is my C ( & Objective-C ) method as follows.

```
void ALERT(NSString *title, NSString *message,NSString *canceBtnTitle,id delegate,NSString *otherButtonTitles, ... )
{
    // HERE I CAN ACCESS ALL THOSE ARGUMENTS
    // BUT I AM NOT SURE How to access additional arguments, supplied using ... ?

UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                  message:message 
                                                 delegate:delegate 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:canceBtnTitle 
                                        otherButtonTitles:// how to pass those params here?];
}
```

As you can notice that, I also have to pass those parameters in `UIAlertView`'s `init` method. I am not sure how to send those parameters into `otherButtonTitles`. I can invoke this method by following ways.

```
ALERT(@"My Alert Title",@"Alert Subtitle",@"YES",viewCtr,@"No",@"May Be",@"Cancel",nil);

ALERT(@"Alert Title",@"Alert Subtitle",@"OK",viewCtr,@"Cancel",nil);

ALERT(@"Alert Title",@"Alert Subtitle",@"OK",viewCtr,nil);

ALERT(@"Alert Title",@"Alert Subtitle",@"OK",viewCtr,@"Option1",@"Option2",nil);
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to get know va_arg (and va_list, va_start, va_end).

[Here's a tutorial on the subject](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html).

Also, [a fine Apple tech note entitled "How can I write a method that takes a variable number of arguments, like NSString's +stringWithFormat:?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html)

Edited to add:

Sounds like you want to do `va_copy`.

Ahh, [here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988290/populating-a-va-list).

Comment: Yep, I got the idea how to access them, But I am not sure, how to pass them as it is to the next function as edited within question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm ! I have gone through [Wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D)

I also learned something from [Michael' Answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8266708/140765).

I have came up with following solution.

```
void ALERT(NSString *title, NSString *message,NSString *canceBtnTitle,id delegate,NSString *otherButtonTitles, ... )
{
    UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title 
                                                      message:message 
                                                     delegate:delegate 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:canceBtnTitle 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil
                            ];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
    NSString *obj;
    for (obj = otherButtonTitles; obj != nil; obj = va_arg(args, NSString*))
        [alertView addButtonWithTitle:obj];
    va_end(args);

    [alertView show];
}
```